# maven unable to resolve dependencies when using version ranges

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

I am using maven 3.x.x and trying to use versions ranges in my pom.xml and it never worked. I tried [version-ordering](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#version-order-testing) suggested by maven and getting the order as expected  on my terminal. But when running maven compile, always getting error as below

```
Failed to execute goal on project test-client: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.abc.def:test-client:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at development.com.abc.test:my-service:jar:jar:[1.0.211006-mr424,1.0.211014-mr427]: No versions available for development.com.abc.test:my-service:jar:jar:[1.0.211006-mr424,1.0.211014-mr427] within specified range -> [Help 1]
```

But if I use the fixed version in my pom.xml, things start working.

my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>development.com.abc.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-service</artifactId>
    <version>[1.0.211006-mr424, 1.0.211014-mr427]</version>
    <classifier>jar</classifier>
</dependency>
```

PS : the artifact uploaded for my-service does not contain maven-metadata.xml in the repository.

The end goal I am trying to achieve is to resolve dynamic dependencies

Comment: Which versions are actually present?

Comment: Version ranges are usually not recommended. For which purpose do you want to use them?

Comment: Do actually need to specify the 'jar' classifier?

Comment: @tgdavies A lot of versions are available including 1.0.211006-mr424 and  1.0.211014-mr427
a few list : 
1.0.211006-mr424, 
1.0.211006-mr425, 
1.0.211006-mr426, 
1.0.211006-mr426, 
1.0.211007-mr421, 
1.0.211007-mr422, 
1.0.211007-mr423, 
1.0.211014-mr427

Comment: @JFabianMeier Its our requirement. Not about recommendation. Assume the artifact is maintained by another team who does frequent changes and we always need to get the latest of it. A basic use case.

Comment: @PiotrMichalczyk : Do you think the issue is with classifier? I tried with and without and it did not work.

Comment: If you have an end to the range, just use that. That is the most recent in the range. Why would you ever want something earlier than mr427 to match?

Comment: @tgdavies the question is about range not working. Not on which version to use. I tried open range pattern as well and it did not work. Whether it is open or closed range, maven should resolve one of the versions which is not happening

Comment: First have you checked that the appropriate repository really contains such version? Because the error message looks like it does not? Most important why do you use a `classifier`? Because if that dependency is a usual jar file you have to remove the classifier...

Comment: @khmarbaise Those are existing versions, and if I use those individual versions, everything works fine with the classifier tag as well.

Comment: Are those projects default jar projects because a classifier is usually not needed nor useful... ?